# How to import a class from ndb.Model?

Tags: python

I'm working with Google App Engine and I want to use my ndb model in another .py file but I couldn't import it.

Here is my main.py;

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    follower_list = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

And this is some code from my cron.py file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

save_user = User.query().filter(User.username == username)
```

But I'm getting:

> ImportError: `No module named User`

How can I import the User class?

Comment: You actually have to import the class you are using.

Comment: Yes, but how? I dont know how to import. This is not django.

Comment: Nothing to do with Django, this is perfectly standard Python. You import the class from the place you define it.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Google App Engine and is a question about standard Python importing.

Comment: You might consider having a separate file for your NDB model class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the model you're just instantiating a class and assigning it to the variable named `User`. In python those variables are bound to the module they were declared in, and there are no implicit globals, so if you want to use it in another module you would need to import it:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import main

save_user = main.User.query().filter(main.User.username == username)
```

However the best practice would be to create the models in a `models.py` file, and import that anytime you need them.

---

BTW, your error hints that you're trying to `import User` earlier in your cron file, is that so? Either way I think you should get the idea now :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to only import the User class rather than the entire "main" module? i.e. "from main import User"

Comment: Yes you're right, it slipped my mind at the time, I was caught up in making the case for the models file, which will then make sense :)

Comment: Don't feel strongly towards it... I wrote it trying to make it as simple as possible for the asker to follow and understand, and he did.